# Glide holds old image cache reference when recycler view scrolls

Tags: android, android-glide

I have list of images to be displayed in a recycler view. I am using Glide lib to load images. Everything is ok and working fine except an annoying thing which has made my life very hard as a developer. When I am scrolling recycler view up/down, Glide holds the old position references and shuffles images to set the actual one after scrolling stops. Images are being loaded from cloudinary url and as well as device local storage path. I am posting my code below. Anyone has any clue or any answer to this problem please help me out. Thanks in advance.

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                .skipMemoryCache(false)
                .signature(new MediaStoreSignature("IMAGE",System.currentTimeMillis(),0))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .override(100, 100)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_round_corner_imageview)
                .error(R.drawable.bg_round_corner_imageview);

Glide.with(mContext)
       .setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions()
                                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
       .asBitmap()
       .load(urlProfileImage)
       .thumbnail(0.1f)
       .apply(requestOptions)                              
       .placeholder(R.drawable.bg_round_corner_imageview)                              
       .error(R.drawable.bg_round_corner_imageview))
       .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable
            Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                view.setImageBitmap(resource);                                       
                view.setBackground(mContext.getResources()                                                .getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_round_corner_imageview));
                view.setClipToOutline(true);
            }
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

try to override **[onViewRecycled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onviewrecycled)** method in the adapter and setting the default/placeholder image.

**For example**

```
@Override
public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
    Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.bg_round_corner_imageview).into(holder.imageview);
}
```

Comment: @ranasaha let me know if you need any help

Comment: @ranasaha Did you check as i suggested?

Comment: Yes but its still the same, previous images getting shuffled and then sets the actual image on scrolling.

Comment: can you show your full code inside onBindViewHolder method?

Answer (score 1):

I think You have put some condition for checking that **urlProfileImage** null or not

If it is null then not call glide and setVisibility == False  ,

if it is not null then load Image with glide and setVisibility == TRUE .

Comment: urlProfileImage is just a variable to store the cloudinary url and I dont have any condition on that like u have mentioned. Its the problem of glide caching actually how far I have understand. But not getting any way to resolve it. Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this line is causing an issue for showing them double while scrolling recycler view. You should properly choose a caching strategy for the guide.

Rather than you should use

```
   .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
```

Comment: Not working, already tried before. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: So this problem was not solved?